# WPF C# Control not rendering inside the "box"

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, pie-chart

For some reason, the **pie menu is not rendered inside the "box"**. Sorry about that, I **have no idea what the is the term for the "box" (see image).**  So it's kinda hard for me to Google the solution since I have no idea what the term is, and the results I get are totally irrelevant

Thus when I want to move/scale the pie menu, it became distorted (like in the picture, where it's width 
went crazy).  As you can see, #2 should be the normal way that an element should be, but in #1, the **entire pie menu went out of the "box"**

**How do I limit the pie slice to be rendered within the "box"?** This control I got it from here, all I did with it was adding properties for customization .

https://o1iu1g.bay.livefilestore.com/y2mlUGn76wNPTpQCZRNgwYZMz1n6Itnr7AB9cUtJQbQ905Q9OaH8JuDPFGIYwEnySfcHzzAd39UxvApLW-vgCj5Vw/WPFPieMenu.zip?download&psid=1

[image]

The code (Not mine, it belongs to the author, I just added some properties)

```
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availablesize)
    {
        foreach (UIElement element in Children)
        {
            element.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
        }

        return availablesize;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalsize)
    {
        double radx = this.DesiredSize.Width / 2.0;
        double rady = this.DesiredSize.Height / 2.0;
        Point center = new Point(radx, rady);

        double angle = 0.0, anglestep = 0.0;

        if (this.Children.Count != 0.0)
            anglestep = TotalAngle / (double)this.Children.Count;

        double deg2rad = Math.PI / 180.0;

        foreach (UIElement uie in Children)
        {
            double a = (angle + anglestep / 2.0) * deg2rad;

            uie.Arrange(new Rect(Point.Add(center, new Vector((radx + (double)base.GetValue(CircularPieMenu.ClippingRadiusProperty)) * Math.Cos(a) / 2.0 - uie.DesiredSize.Width / 2.0, 
                                                                (rady + (double)base.GetValue(CircularPieMenu.ClippingRadiusProperty)) * Math.Sin(a) / 2.0 - uie.DesiredSize.Height / 2.0)), 
                                           uie.DesiredSize));

            angle += anglestep;
        }

        return finalsize;
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        double radx = this.DesiredSize.Width / 2.0;
        double rady = this.DesiredSize.Height / 2.0;
        Size radiusSize = new Size(radx, rady);
        Point center = new Point(radx, rady);

        double currentAngle = 0.0;
        double angleStep = 0.0;

        if (this.Children.Count != 0.0)
        {
            angleStep = TotalAngle / (double)this.Children.Count;
        }

        double deg2rad = Math.PI / 180.0;

        // this is the code where caused the "hole" in the center of the "ellipse"
        EllipseGeometry entirePart = new EllipseGeometry(center, radx + 1, rady + 1);
        EllipseGeometry excludedPart = new EllipseGeometry(center, ClippingRadius, ClippingRadius);
        dc.PushClip(new CombinedGeometry(GeometryCombineMode.Exclude, entirePart, excludedPart));

        // this produce a full ellipse (not like arc segment like u would think)
        // we want to have arcs, instead of a full ellipse :D
        dc.DrawEllipse(BackgroundColor, new Pen(OuterCircumferenceColor, OuterCircumferenceThickness), center, radx, rady);

        if (ClippingRadius > 0.0)
        {
            dc.DrawEllipse(null, new Pen(InnerCircumferenceColor, 1.0), center, ClippingRadius + 1, ClippingRadius + 1);
        }

        double startAngle = 0.0, endAngle = 0.0;

        foreach (UIElement element in this.Children)
        {
            double angle = currentAngle * deg2rad;

            // line between segments
            dc.DrawLine(new Pen(LineColor, LineThickness), center, Point.Add(center, new Vector(radx * Math.Cos(angle), rady * Math.Sin(angle))));

            if (this.IsMouseOver && element.IsMouseOver)
            {
                startAngle = angle;
                endAngle = startAngle + angleStep * deg2rad;
            }

            currentAngle += angleStep;
        }

        // only related when mouse down
        if (this.IsMouseOver)
        {
            PathGeometry path = new PathGeometry();
            PathFigure pathfig = new PathFigure();
            pathfig.StartPoint = center;
            pathfig.Segments.Add(new LineSegment(Point.Add(center, new Vector(radx * Math.Cos(startAngle), rady * Math.Sin(startAngle))), true));
            pathfig.Segments.Add(new ArcSegment(Point.Add(center, new Vector(radx * Math.Cos(endAngle), rady * Math.Sin(endAngle))), new Size(1.0, 1.0), 0.0, false, SweepDirection.Clockwise, true));
            pathfig.Segments.Add(new LineSegment(center, true));
            path.Figures.Add(pathfig);
            dc.PushClip(path);
            currentAngle = 0;

            if (this.ismouseleftdown)
            {
                dc.DrawEllipse(ForegroundColor, new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(171, 161, 140)), 1.0), center, radx, rady);
                dc.DrawEllipse(null, new Pen(new LinearGradientBrush(Color.FromRgb(223, 183, 136), Colors.Transparent, 45.0), 1.0), center, radx - 1, rady - 1);

                if ((double)base.GetValue(CircularPieMenu.ClippingRadiusProperty) > 0.0)
                    dc.DrawEllipse(null, new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(171, 161, 140)), 1.0), center, (double)base.GetValue(CircularPieMenu.ClippingRadiusProperty) + 1, (double)base.GetValue(CircularPieMenu.ClippingRadiusProperty) + 1);

                foreach (UIElement uie in this.Children)
                {
                    double a = currentAngle * deg2rad;
                    dc.DrawLine(new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(171, 161, 140)), 1.0), center, Point.Add(center, new Vector(radx * Math.Cos(a), rady * Math.Sin(a))));

                    currentAngle += angleStep;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // chg to mouse over color                                       circumference color
                dc.DrawEllipse(ForegroundColor, new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(210, 192, 141)), 1.0), center, radx, rady);
                //dc.DrawEllipse(null, new Pen(new LinearGradientBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 247), Colors.Transparent, 45.0), 1.0), center, radx - 1, rady - 1);

                if ((double)base.GetValue(CircularPieMenu.ClippingRadiusProperty) > 0.0)
                    dc.DrawEllipse(null, new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(210, 192, 141)), 1.0), center, (double)base.GetValue(CircularPieMenu.ClippingRadiusProperty) + 1, (double)base.GetValue(CircularPieMenu.ClippingRadiusProperty) + 1);

                foreach (UIElement uie in this.Children)
                {
                    double a = currentAngle * deg2rad;
                    dc.DrawLine(new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(210, 192, 141)), 1.0), center, Point.Add(center, new Vector(radx * Math.Cos(a), rady * Math.Sin(a))));

                    currentAngle += angleStep;
                }
            }

            dc.Pop();
        }

        dc.Pop();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Math.Min(RenderSize.Width/2, RenderSize.Height/2) instead.

Summarize of the cause of the problem : careless mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The Measure Override is just returning the available size it got. It is not supposed to be like that. It should return the size needed for the control and its children. See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058(v=vs.110).aspx#LayoutSystem_Measure_Arrange) for two pass layout system in WPF.

In your case, the control should find the diameter of PIE and that should be return as the size constraint.

Comment: It seems like it's the same after I returned the diameter of the pie. The pie slices still are outside of the "box". Do you think I should treat them as a child of the panel by creating new Item class for it?

Comment: Each slice should be default item container of Pie Menu (considering Pie menu as ItemsControl)

Comment: The pie menu is a panel actually :/
Does that means each slice should have rendering done by itself instead of doing the rendering for all of the slices in pie menu?

Comment: Yes. Make Pie as an ItemsControl and add slices as its items. Then make this panel as ItemsPanel of that Pie control.